# Redmine on Gentoo: undefined method `active_record' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x00000000ea5538> (NoMethodError)

Tags: activerecord, passenger, redmine, postgresql-9.1, gentoo

Running Redmine on Gentoo is hell on earth (at least for me as I have not much clue about ruby)! I'm currently "running" Redmine 2.3.2 via passenger and apache and since some days all i get is

```
undefined method `active_record' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x00000000ea5538> (NoMethodError)
  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:85:in `method_missing'
  /var/lib/redmine/config/application.rb:26:in `<class:Application>'
  /var/lib/redmine/config/application.rb:13:in `<module:RedmineApp>'
  /var/lib/redmine/config/application.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/lib64/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require'
  /usr/lib64/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require'
  /var/lib/redmine/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/lib64/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require'
  /usr/lib64/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require'
  config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
  config.ru:1:in `new'
  config.ru:1:in `<main>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:82:in `eval'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:82:in `preload_app'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:127:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:6:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:5:in `<main>'
```

emerge --config produces a similar error

```
# emerge --config "=www-apps/redmine-2.3.2"


Configuring pkg...

 * 
 * Upgrading database.
 * 
 * Migrating database.
rake aborted!
undefined method `active_record' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x0000000060bf80>
/var/lib/redmine/config/application.rb:26:in `<class:Application>'
/var/lib/redmine/config/application.rb:13:in `<module:RedmineApp>'
/var/lib/redmine/config/application.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/redmine/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
 * ERROR: www-apps/redmine-2.3.2::gentoo failed (config phase):
 *   (no error message)
 * 
 * Call stack:
 *     ebuild.sh, line  93:  Called pkg_config
 *   environment, line 4030:  Called die
 * The specific snippet of code:
 *           RAILS_ENV="${RAILS_ENV}" ${RUBY} -S rake db:migrate || die;
 * 
 * If you need support, post the output of `emerge --info '=www-apps/redmine-2.3.2::gentoo'`,
 * the complete build log and the output of `emerge -pqv '=www-apps/redmine-2.3.2::gentoo'`.
!!! When you file a bug report, please include the following information:
GENTOO_VM=  CLASSPATH="" JAVA_HOME=""
JAVACFLAGS="" COMPILER=""
and of course, the output of emerge --info =redmine-2.3.2
 * The complete build log is located at '/var/tmp/portage/www-apps/redmine-2.3.2/temp/build.log'.
 * The ebuild environment file is located at '/var/tmp/portage/www-apps/redmine-2.3.2/temp/environment'.
 * Working directory: '/var/lib/redmine'
 * S: '/var/tmp/portage/www-apps/redmine-2.3.2/work/redmine-2.3.2'
```

I already

- re-installed redmine
- re-installed passenger
- updated/rebuilt all my manually installed gems
- removed all gems (local and systemwide) and re-installed redmine with all dependencies

I'm kind of lost here, any help would be appreciated.

Here is some more Gentoo-related information:

emerge --info

```
Portage 2.1.12.2 (hardened/linux/amd64, gcc-4.6.3-hardenednopiessp, glibc-2.15-r3, 3.6.11-GN-SMP_x86_64 x86_64)
=================================================================
System uname: Linux-3.6.11-GN-SMP_x86_64-x86_64-Intel-R-_Core-TM-2_Duo_CPU_T7700_@_2.40GHz-with-gentoo-2.2
KiB Mem:     6114288 total,   3688836 free
KiB Swap:    2097612 total,   2097612 free
Timestamp of tree: Fri, 13 Sep 2013 12:30:01 +0000
ld GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.23.1
ccache version 3.1.9 [enabled]
app-shells/bash:          4.2_p45
dev-java/java-config:     2.1.12-r1
dev-lang/python:          2.7.5-r2, 3.2.5-r2
dev-util/ccache:          3.1.9
dev-util/cmake:           2.8.10.2-r2
dev-util/pkgconfig:       0.28
sys-apps/baselayout:      2.2
sys-apps/openrc:          0.11.8
sys-apps/sandbox:         2.6-r1
sys-devel/autoconf:       2.13, 2.69
sys-devel/automake:       1.11.6, 1.12.6, 1.13.4
sys-devel/binutils:       2.23.1
sys-devel/gcc:            4.6.3
sys-devel/gcc-config:     1.7.3
sys-devel/libtool:        2.4-r1
sys-devel/make:           3.82-r4
sys-kernel/linux-headers: 3.9 (virtual/os-headers)
sys-libs/glibc:           2.15-r3
Repositories: gentoo
ACCEPT_KEYWORDS="amd64"
ACCEPT_LICENSE="* -@EULA dlj-1.1 Oracle-BCLA-JavaSE"
CBUILD="x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"
CFLAGS="-march=native -O2 -pipe"
CHOST="x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"
CONFIG_PROTECT="/etc /usr/share/gnupg/qualified.txt /usr/share/maven-bin-3.0/conf /var/lib/redmine/config"
CONFIG_PROTECT_MASK="/etc/ca-certificates.conf /etc/env.d /etc/fonts/fonts.conf /etc/gconf /etc/gentoo-release /etc/php/apache2-php5.4/ext-active/ /etc/php/apache2-php5.5/ext-active/ /etc/php/cgi-php5.4/ext-active/ /etc/php/cgi-php5.5/ext-active/ /etc/php/cli-php5.4/ext-active/ /etc/php/cli-php5.5/ext-active/ /etc/revdep-rebuild /etc/sandbox.d /etc/terminfo /var/lib/redmine/config/locales /var/lib/redmine/config/settings.yml"
CXXFLAGS="-march=native -O2 -pipe"
DISTDIR="/usr/portage/distfiles"
EMERGE_DEFAULT_OPTS="--quiet --keep-going"
FCFLAGS="-O2 -pipe"
FEATURES="assume-digests binpkg-logs ccache config-protect-if-modified distlocks ebuild-locks fixlafiles merge-sync news parallel-fetch parallel-install preserve-libs protect-owned sandbox sfperms strict unknown-features-warn unmerge-logs unmerge-orphans userfetch userpriv xattr"
FFLAGS="-O2 -pipe"
GENTOO_MIRRORS="http://distfiles.gentoo.org"
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LDFLAGS="-Wl,-O1 -Wl,--as-needed"
MAKEOPTS="-j5"
PKGDIR="/usr/portage/packages"
PORTAGE_CONFIGROOT="/"
PORTAGE_RSYNC_OPTS="--recursive --links --safe-links --perms --times --compress --force --whole-file --delete --stats --human-readable --timeout=180 --exclude=/distfiles --exclude=/local --exclude=/packages"
PORTAGE_TMPDIR="/var/tmp"
PORTDIR="/usr/portage"
PORTDIR_OVERLAY=""
SYNC="rsync://rsync.gentoo.org/gentoo-portage"
USE="acl amd64 bash-completion berkdb bzip2 cli cracklib crypt cxx dri gdbm hardened iconv ipv6 justify mmx modules mudflap multilib ncurses nls nptl openmp pam pax_kernel pcre readline session sse sse2 ssl tcpd unicode urandom utf8 vim-syntax zlib" ABI_X86="64" ALSA_CARDS="ali5451 als4000 atiixp atiixp-modem bt87x ca0106 cmipci emu10k1x ens1370 ens1371 es1938 es1968 fm801 hda-intel intel8x0 intel8x0m maestro3 trident usb-audio via82xx via82xx-modem ymfpci" APACHE2_MODULES="actions alias auth_basic authn_alias authn_anon authn_dbm authn_default authn_file authz_dbm authz_default authz_groupfile authz_host authz_owner authz_user cache dav dav_fs dav_lock deflate dir disk_cache env expires ext_filter file_cache filter headers include log_config logio mem_cache mime mime_magic negotiation rewrite setenvif speling unique_id usertrack vhost_alias autoindex cgi perl proxy proxy_ajp" CALLIGRA_FEATURES="kexi words flow plan sheets stage tables krita karbon braindump author" CAMERAS="ptp2" COLLECTD_PLUGINS="df interface irq load memory rrdtool swap syslog" ELIBC="glibc" GPSD_PROTOCOLS="ashtech aivdm earthmate evermore fv18 garmin garmintxt gpsclock itrax mtk3301 nmea ntrip navcom oceanserver oldstyle oncore rtcm104v2 rtcm104v3 sirf superstar2 timing tsip tripmate tnt ubx" INPUT_DEVICES="keyboard mouse evdev" KERNEL="linux" LCD_DEVICES="bayrad cfontz cfontz633 glk hd44780 lb216 lcdm001 mtxorb ncurses text" LIBREOFFICE_EXTENSIONS="presenter-console presenter-minimizer" LINGUAS="de" OFFICE_IMPLEMENTATION="libreoffice" PHP_TARGETS="php5-4" PYTHON_SINGLE_TARGET="python2_7" PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7 python3_2" RUBY_TARGETS="ruby19" USERLAND="GNU" VIDEO_CARDS="fbdev glint intel mach64 mga nouveau nv r128 radeon savage sis tdfx trident vesa via vmware dummy v4l" XTABLES_ADDONS="quota2 psd pknock lscan length2 ipv4options ipset ipp2p iface geoip fuzzy condition tee tarpit sysrq steal rawnat logmark ipmark dhcpmac delude chaos account"
Unset:  CPPFLAGS, CTARGET, INSTALL_MASK, LC_ALL, PORTAGE_BUNZIP2_COMMAND, PORTAGE_COMPRESS, PORTAGE_COMPRESS_FLAGS, PORTAGE_RSYNC_EXTRA_OPTS, USE_PYTHON
=================================================================
                    Package Settings
=================================================================

www-apps/redmine-2.3.2 was built with the following:
USE="imagemagick ldap (multilib) passenger -fastcgi -openid -test" ABI_X86="64" RUBY_TARGETS="ruby19 -ruby18"
```

Ruby version:

```
#eselect ruby list
Available Ruby profiles:
  [1]   ruby18
  [2]   ruby19 (with Rubygems) *
  [3]   ruby20 (with Rubygems)
```

Installed ruby dependencies:

```
# qlist -ICv dev-ruby
dev-ruby/abstract-1.0.0-r1
dev-ruby/actionmailer-3.2.14
dev-ruby/actionpack-3.2.14
dev-ruby/activemodel-3.2.14
dev-ruby/activerecord-3.2.14
dev-ruby/activeresource-3.2.14
dev-ruby/activesupport-3.2.14
dev-ruby/arel-3.0.2-r1
dev-ruby/bcrypt-ruby-3.1.2
dev-ruby/builder-3.0.4
dev-ruby/builder-3.2.2
dev-ruby/bundler-1.3.5
dev-ruby/coderay-1.1.0
dev-ruby/coffee-rails-3.2.2
dev-ruby/coffee-script-2.2.0
dev-ruby/coffee-script-source-1.6.3
dev-ruby/erubis-2.7.0
dev-ruby/execjs-2.0.1
dev-ruby/ffi-1.4.0
dev-ruby/hike-1.2.3
dev-ruby/i18n-0.6.5
dev-ruby/journey-1.0.4
dev-ruby/jquery-rails-2.3.0
dev-ruby/json-1.8.0-r1
dev-ruby/listen-0.7.3
dev-ruby/mail-2.5.4
dev-ruby/mime-types-1.23
dev-ruby/multi_json-1.6.1
dev-ruby/pg-0.16.0
dev-ruby/polyglot-0.3.3
dev-ruby/racc-1.4.9
dev-ruby/rack-1.4.5-r1
dev-ruby/rack-cache-1.2
dev-ruby/rack-ssl-1.3.3
dev-ruby/rack-test-0.6.2
dev-ruby/rails-3.2.14
dev-ruby/railties-3.2.14
dev-ruby/rake-0.9.6
dev-ruby/rake-compiler-0.9.1
dev-ruby/rb-inotify-0.9.1
dev-ruby/rdoc-4.0.1-r1
dev-ruby/rmagick-2.13.2
dev-ruby/ruby-net-ldap-0.3.1
dev-ruby/rubygems-2.0.8
dev-ruby/sass-3.2.10
dev-ruby/sass-rails-3.2.6
dev-ruby/sprockets-2.2.2-r1
dev-ruby/thor-0.18.1
dev-ruby/tilt-1.4.1
dev-ruby/treetop-1.4.15
dev-ruby/tzinfo-1.0.1
dev-ruby/uglifier-2.2.1
dev-ruby/yard-0.8.7
```

dev-ruby/activerecord connects to a postgres 9.1 server and has these use flags:

```
dev-ruby/activerecord-3.2.14  USE="postgres -mysql -sqlite3 {-test}" RUBY_TARGETS="ruby19 -ruby18"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Holy cow I solved it myself!

It seems that the dependencies Gentoo pulls in are not valid.

I manually downloaded the Gemfile from

```
http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/repository/entry/tags/2.3.2/Gemfile
```

and ran

```
bundle install --without development test
```

After everything was installed

```
emerge --config "=www-apps/redmine-2.3.2
```

ran flawlessly and Redmine came up after I restarted apache!

I hope this post helps other Gentoo users as well.

Comment: Had the same problem about missing active_record. Thanks a ton, your solution... (still in process). Feels weird because I didn't know what I'm doing. I also had to install ImageMagick manuall because some native extension of gem rmagick failed to build.
Seems to me the redmine ebuilds need fixing. But I wouldn't know how...

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, after following your answer, still got the
'cannot load such file -- /var/lib/redmine/config/environment' error.

Solved it by doing a 'chown -R apache:apache /var/lib/redmine'

Aparently some update changed the ownership of the files to the 'redmine' user.

it's working for me now.